# I can't boot from a hard drive on usb

Tags: boot, usb, hard-drive, laptop

My Samsung laptop came with a hard drive and I installed Ubuntu on it. Now I upgraded for a SSD that I also installed Ubuntu. I want to be able to boot from the hard drive through the USB so I can export some settings.
I was able to do that on my old laptop, but here when I try with Samsung BIOS settings or f10 on boot the hard drive shuts down and the laptop restarts.
I can access the hard drive contents as a mass storage device so I know it's not corrupted.
On the Samsung BIOS security tab the HDD password is shown as "frozen" but the hard drive doesn't have a password, but sometimes it shows as clear but even then I wasn't able to boot.

Comment: You've not provided any Ubuntu product/release details, but you can only boot from devices your machine's *firmware* will allow booting from.  Some devices are more difficult than others (eg. I've a samsung device here I don't use in QA or *Quality Assurance* testing in Ubuntu much, as its no fun to external media from)

Comment: If the device is a spinning disk hard drive, you’ll want to also confirm that the unit is receiving enough power to handle a boot cycle. There is a lot of reading and writing going on when a machine starts up, and sometimes the power supplied by the USB port is insufficient 

Comment: Set the HDD as first boot device. Boot from the hard drive. In Terminal run: `sudo update-grub`. This will add the SSD to the HDD's boot menu. Boot may be a little slower from HDD than from SSD.